# Storing two values in a checkbox php

Tags: php

I'm trying to record the attendance of each student, I was able to retrieve the value of the checkbox (Late, Excuse, Absent). Is there a way that I can get both the student ID and the attendance mark from the checkbox? I need to pair the student ID with his/her attendance mark.

```html
<!-- I want to get the student ID, to save his/her Mark(Late,Absent,Excused) -->


<form action="WorkLoad_attendance.php" method="post">      
<div id="employee_table" class="" >  
<table class="table table-bordered">
<?php 
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smis");  
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  ST.*,SL.*,W.*,C.className,SJ.* FROM studentdata ST,workloaddata W,subject_studentlist_data Sl,classdata C,subjectdata SJ 
 WHERE (((((SL.studentList_studentID = ST.studentID)and(SL.studentList_WorkloadID = W.WorkloadID))and(W.Workload_classID= C.classID)) and SL.studentList_subjectID =SJ.subjectID) and SL.Enrollment_Status ='Enrolled') and W.WorkloadID=$WID";   
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
?>
 <tr>  
 <th width="27%">Student Name</th>                                     
 <th width="25%">Class Name</th>
 <th width="23%">Subject Name</th>          
 <th width="9%">Present But Late</th>
 <th width="9%">Excuse</th>
 <th width="7%">Absent</th>          
 </tr>  
     <?php  
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
     {             
     ?>  

 <tr>  
 <td><?php echo  "&nbsp;".$row["Lname"].", &nbsp;".$row["Fname"] ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo  "&nbsp;".$row["className"] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo  "&nbsp;".$row["subjectName"] ?></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" value=""><label>&nbsp; Late</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" value="Excused"><label>&nbsp;Excused</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="mark[]" value="Absent"><label>&nbsp;Absent</label></td>                </tr> 
 <input type="hidden" name="A_StudentlistID" value="<?php echo $row["studentList_studentID"];?>     
<?php           
 }                                       
mysqli_close($connect);          
 ?>  
 </table>
 
<input type="button" name="ResetSelected" value="Reset Selected" class="btnCheckboxes2 " />
<input type="submit" name="RecordAttendance" value="Record Attendance" class="btnCheckboxes " />      
         </div> 
      </form >      




<?php

if(isset($_POST['RecordAttendance']))
 {  //$StudentID = $_POST['markAttendance'];
    $A_StudentlistID = $_POST['A_StudentlistID'];
 $SL_subjectID = $_POST['SL_subjectID'];
echo "student list:  $A_StudentlistID";

 if( isset($_POST['mark']) && is_array($_POST['mark']) ) {
    foreach($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
        // Displaying mark for testing"
        echo "<br>student list:  $A_StudentlistID Attendance Mark {$mark}!<br>";
  
        // -- insert into database call will go here
    }
 }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Checkbox is for multiple selection. How any student is late and absent ? You should use radio.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I've changed the input to "radio" and the solution that @Quentin provided works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the student ID in the name. PHP's non-standard form processing routines will inflate it to the key in an associative array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mark[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>]" value="Late">
```

Then when you process them, you can loop over them:

```
foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $student_id => $attendance) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($student_id) . " was " . htmlspecialchars($attendance) . ".";
}
```

Comment: @C2486 — Yes, it will work for a checkbox. That's why I recommended it and gave a checkbox in the example code. It will give an associative array, that's why I wrote an example showing how to process the associative array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same student_id in multiple values:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="mark[0_1]" value="Late"><label>&nbsp; Late</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mark[1_1]" value="Excused"><label>&nbsp; Excused</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mark[2_2]" value="Absent"><label>&nbsp; Absent</label>

foreach($_POST['mark'] as $key => $value) {
  $exp = explode('_', $key);
  $student_id = (int)$exp[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score -1):

sure. Use a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $theStudentId;?>" />
```

then grab it right by the name

```
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
```

Comment: That table will display all the student enrolled in the class, I've put the hidden field but when I've to echoed it for testing it will only return one Student ID. Which most probably the last student ID retrieved from my query.

Comment: please provide more source code and I can help out further.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.